# What would be trigonometry if we included infinite triangles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

What would be trigonometry if we included triangles of infinite area or with infinite sides and introduced ways to compare them etc?

Comment: Relate it as well as you can with $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ maybe?

Comment: Can you give an example of what issues this would cover?  Not sure I see that it'd be *any* different.  We'd allow for $\tan \frac \pi 2 = \infty$, I guess and parallel lines intersecting at infinte antipodes I guess but those are .... "childish diversions".

Comment: @fleablood for instance, a triangle whose two angles are greater than 180 deg (and the third, negative angle is at "infinity"...

Comment: That'd have to be an angle with negative angle.  But what what statements are you saying about triangles where the angles are not? Are you thinking something like the law of cosines if $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos C$ so if $A=120$ and $B=90$ and $C=-30$ and $a=\infty_1$ and $b=\infty_2$ and $c=6$ then $36=\infty_1^2+\infty_2^2-2\infty_1\infty_2^2\cos(-30)=\infty_1^2+\infty_2^2-2\infty_1\infty_2\frac{\sqrt 3}2$. $\infty_1^2 = \infty_2^2+36-12\infty_2\cos 120=\infty_2^2+36-6\infty_2$ and $\infty_2^2 = \infty_1^2+36-12\infty_2\cos 90=\infty_1^2+36-\infty_2\cdot 0$.  It's fun word games but....

Comment: @anixx in your "inside out" triangle I would not put the negative anglexat infinity.  If you extend the two sides that point away from each other the "wrong way" they meet at some point "outside" your triangle.  There is where I'd put your negative angle.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi one can do so, but in this case the length of two sides will also be negative (rather than infinite).

Comment: Exactly.  And all the usual trigonometric relations (e.g. Law of Sines) will work with those negative sides and angle!

Comment: @OscarLanzi yes, but another question, whether they would work with infinite sides and areas...

Comment: At least the Law of Sines does, if two sides are _parallel_.  Put two infinite sides and a zero included angle into this equation.  For the Law of Cosines you would need to solve for the cosine of an angle first.

Comment: @OscarLanzi well, when I say "infinite" I do not mean affine or projective infinity. I mean something like this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651 Notice that if we consider $\int_0^\infty x^n dx$, the regular part of the integral is zero. Thus $\int_0^1 x^n dx=-\operatorname{reg}\int_1^\infty x^n dx$. In other words, if we take a triangle and adjanced to it infinite triangle, the area of the infinite triangle would have regular (finite) part equal to the first triangle but negative (this is like regularization of infinite series).

Comment: @OscarLanzi The infinite part would be more complicated - it would depend on the position of the coordinate zero and on the ordering (filtering) of the space (so the area of infinite triangles depends on their position, which is not surprizing given that we can just by shift put one inside the other, otherwise similar).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would look like [hyperbolic trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#Trigonometry), i.e. the trigonometry of triangles in the [hyperbolic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry), where infinite triangles also known as "ideal triangles" live very naturally.

Comment: Good example, but what about something like this but in Euclidean geometry?